# EF Core 6 trying to read from appsettings.json but I don't want that

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have an EF Core application that was working fine with `UseSqlServer` option where I was reading the connection string from a property in `appsettings.json` called `MyDbConnectionString`.

The problem started when I introduced `ConnectionString` under a parent property `AppInsights`. The `DbContext` is now seeing this new `ConnectionString` and is throwing errors that the connection string is not in the right format. I don't want the `DbContext` to worry about the `appsettings.json` and want it to continue using the connection string that I supplied.

How can I ask EF core to not bother about `appsettings.json` ?

Code:

```
 var configurationFile = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appSettings.json");
            _config = configurationFile.Build();
            string ihcSqlDatabaseConnectionString = _config.GetSection("Settings")["IhcSqlDatabaseConnectionString"];
            string DatabaseConnectionString = string.Concat(ihcSqlDatabaseConnectionString, ";persist security info = True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;");
            IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddServices();
            serviceCollection.AddDbContext<ProxyServiceDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(DatabaseConnectionString));
```

Comment: We need more context as we don't have any insight as to what your code looks like. Show us. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Added code. Let me know if you need more code about where the injection of the repository happens and related areas.

Answer (score 0):

The EF core will use the connection string which you have set when you inject the dbcontext service.

I guess you use the wrong connection string for the `AppInsights`, please make sure it is right.

For example. you could define a property like AppInsights and it contains the right connection string and then use it inside the dbcontext.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
var AppInsights ="Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(AppInsights));
```

Comment: I use it like this but still, it's reading from the app insights connection string which is baffling me.
```
"Settings": {
    "IhcSqlDatabaseConnectionString": "xyz",
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "e73a7170-5290-4562-bbb8-c85809f499d4"
  },
```
you can see that db connection string is fetched from a different property and appinsights logging uses a different property

Comment: Please post more details about the _config, did you set the config from other codes?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the DB context is evaluating its logger which is app insights. My appsettings.json had an invalid value for appsettings.json which was the reason for the exception. The db connection string was correctly used and not taken from appinsights connection string.